# Local Git Hook Pre-Commit/Pre-Push does not run (Windows)

Tags: git, powershell, github, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I have a repo set up which is supposed to run a fairly simple pre-push/pre-commit powershell script (It doesn't really matter when the script executes). However, for the life of me I cannot get it to run. 
I have tried to use `chmod +x .git/hooks/*` and `chmod ug+x .git/hooks/*`
I have tried editing the `#!/bin/...` and even removing it all together as I have read it is not supported in Windows.
I know the script works because when I call it via `& C:\Users\...\.git\hooks\pre-commit.ps1` it works.

For what it's worth here is my script to be run:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Script Running"
& 'C:\Users\Ian Pennebaker\Desktop\RevisionDate.vbs'
Start-Sleep -s 30
& 'C:\Users\Ian Pennebaker\Desktop\MovePDF.vbs'
cd 'C:\Users\Ian Pennebaker\desktop\Test2'
pdftk *.pdf cat output ECMWC.pdf
& 'C:\Users\Ian Pennebaker\Desktop\DeleteAllButFinal.vbs'
```

It is currently named pre-push.ps1 but like I said earlier it could also be used at pre-commit or any other hook location. 
Does anybody have any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your file `pre-commit.ps1` to `pre-commit`.